# Numpy: How to unwrap of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am hoping to reshape matrices in such a form

```
A = 
[[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]]

B = 
[[10,11,12],
[13,14,15],
[16,17,18]]

Z = [[1, 2, 3 10, 11, 12],
[4, 5, 6, 13, 14, 15],
[7,8,9, 16, 17 ,18]]
```

Where A,B are a 3x3 matrices but z is a 3x6 matrix. I'd like to be able to apply it to higher dimensions.
`np.ravel` returns a flattened array so I can't use that because the output matrix will then be

```
Z = 
[[1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12],
[13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]]
```

I can't use `np.reshape` to `(6,6)` either because it would flatten the array before, since it results in the same matrix as above. Looking for some way to implement this.

Comment: `np.hstack((A.ravel(), B.ravel())).reshape(3,6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `A` and `B` are always the same shape:

```
np.vstack((A, B)).reshape(len(A), -1)

#array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
#       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
#       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]])
```